# Retaining newlines in input form

Tags: django

I realise there are many questions similar to this, but they all seem to answer the flip-side: "How do I display..."

I can show that I'm not getting the newlines from the request object

### environment

django 2.2.1, qunicorn 19.9.0

.. running in a docker image build on a python 3.7 base image

### setup

Pre-populate a database record:

```
update api_entitlement set notes= E'line 1\nline2\nline3' where guid='44aa651c-ea98-4990-aa85-d87d21db6043';
```

.... and confirm the data is there:

```
select * from api_entitlement where guid='44aa651c-ea98-4990-aa85-d87d21db6043';
  id   |                 guid                 | notes  
-------+--------------------------------------+--------
 14053 | 44aa651c-ea98-4990-aa85-d87d21db6043 | line 1+
       |                                      | line2 +
       |                                      | line3
(1 row)
```

The fragment of template that creates the `textarea` is thus:

```
<pre id="{{ entitlement.guid }}_notes">{% if entitlement.notes == '—' or
  entitlement.notes is None %}—{% else %}{{ entitlement.notes }}
  {% endif %}</pre><textarea id="{{ entitlement.guid }}_notes_new"
  type="text" class="form-control" value="{% if entitlement.notes == '—' %}
  -{% else %}{{ entitlement.notes }}{% endif %}" style="display:none">{{
  entitlement.notes }}</textarea>
```

(there's some javascript that toggles from *display* to *edit*, from the `<pre>` to the `<textarea>`)

and the code that reads the form is thus:

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       logger.info(f"notes value is {request.GET}")
       #
       # snip irrelevant code
            #
            value = request.GET.get('notes')
            logger.info(f"notes value is {value}")
            if value != '-' and entitlement.notes != value:
                entitlement.notes = value
            #
            # ... and even more
```

### In use

If I simple display the page, I get the 3-lines from the database, as three separate lines - this is good.

If I toggle to edit mode, I get a 3-line input form, with three lines on it.
I'll edit the data so lines 2 & 3 have spaces before their digits, and submit the form

The `logger.info` line logs `notes value is <QueryDict: {'notes': ['line 1line 2line 3']}>`
.... the newlines have been removed.

### Why?

.... and, more importantly, how do I retain them?

I did have the `whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware` middlewhere imported, but I've removed that - made no difference

Comment: are you using js to get the textarea value?

Comment: @NalinDobhal - as mentioned in the question, I get the value with `value = request.GET.get('notes')` ..... but even the value dump of `logger.info(f"notes value is {request.GET}")` is showing no new lines